# Visual Studio C# - Reverse !Enabled foreach Checkbox if unchecked?

Tags: c#, checkbox, foreach

I have a bunch of checkboxes in a groupbox. I want to make it so when one is checked, all the others are disabled. I have the following code in a checkchanged event applied to all the checkboxes in the groupbox, which does what I wanted above but, I want to reverse this when you uncheck that box. How do I do so?

```
foreach (CheckBox chk in this.grpBreadType.Controls)
{
    if (!chk.Checked)
    {
        chk.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Pictures

[When you check a box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBnn7.png)

[When you uncheck that box :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkcQR.png)

Comment: thats called a combobox... or a set of radiobuttons

Comment: wouldn't a radiobutton server a better purpose here. They are mutually exclusive in the same parent.

Comment: if you're talking about a group of checkboxes needs to be disabled or enabled based on another checkbox then you could put those inside a panel and just enable/disable the panel based on the first checkbox.

Comment: Radio buttons would work but I've made a workaround for it because I don't want radiobuttons and checkboxes beside each other. I want to make it so, when all boxes are unchecked, all of them will be re-enabled.

Comment: I've added some pictures for 1 of my groupboxes, later (in the other groupboxes) I'd want the user to be able to select multiple but still keep the style of checkboxes through-out the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may do what you're wanting.

```
private void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox tmp = (CheckBox)sender;
        bool tmpStatus = tmp.Checked;
        foreach (CheckBox chk in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            if (tmp.Checked)
            {
                chk.Enabled = false;
                tmp.Enabled = tmpStatus;
            }
            else
            {
                chk.Enabled = true;
                tmp.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

You would point all your checkbox's CheckChanged events to this sub. Could probably use a little refactoring too.

Comment: I tried this but nothing happens. I inserted a break point at the if statement and it does not detect it when I check the box. I did point my checkbox's CheckChanged events.

Comment: Did you point all your checkbox's checkchanged events to this routine. (ie, hilight the checkboxes involved, click on the event icon in the properties window, scroll down to checkchanged, select this sub in the dropdown.

Comment: I tried your code block on a new form and it seemed to work perfectly with the exception of all checkboxes being disabled. I'm trying to figure out why it's not working on my actual project. - Looks like it doesn't apply to the groupbox but to the form...

Comment: Keep in mind that my code is based on checkboxes on the form. Your application has checkboxes inside a groupbox so you will need to look at controls inside the groupbox. this.Controls. would need changed to this.grpBreadType.

Comment: Got you, so instead of... this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) I'll do this; this.groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())

Comment: if indeed your groupbox is named groupBox1.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much for allowing me your time, I'm going to give you full credit. groupBox1 was just in my test app, not my main :)